# How to optimize the computation speed in array.forEach in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, foreach, computation

I have a piece of code simply loops through two arrays and for each element of the first array, it finds the relevant element in the second array and changes only the first occurrence and delete the remaining ones.

```js
 /**
     * The aggregation data structure:
     * "_id": {
     * "geometry": geometry,
     * "dups": [
     *    "5b3b25b4e54029249c459bfc", keep only the fisrt element in allDocs
     *    "5b3b25b4e54029249c459e65", delete it from allDocs
     *    "5b3b25b4e54029249c459d7d"   delete it from allDocs
     *   ],
     * "dupsProp": [  ], array of all properties of duplicatePoints
     * "count": 3
     */
var aggregationRes =[46,000 objects]
var allDocs =[345,000 objects]
aggregationRes.forEach(function (resElem, counter) {
        console.log(counter + "/" + aggregationRes.length)
        //Delete objects in allDocs based on dups array except the first one
        var foundIndex = allDocs.findIndex(x => x._id.toString() == resElem.dups[0]);
                //assign the mergedProperties
        allDocs[foundIndex].properties = resElem.dupsProp;
        //delete the remaining ids in Docs from dups array 
        resElem.dups.forEach(function (dupElem, index) {
            var tmpFoundIndex = allDocs.findIndex(x => x._id.toString() == resElem.dups[index + 1]);
            if (tmpFoundIndex !== -1) {
                allDocs.splice(tmpFoundIndex, 1)
            }
        })
    })
```

This script runs almost for 4 hours. As you see, the calculations are really simple but since the allDocs array is big, it takes quite a long time. It would be great if someone gives me a hint on how to decrease the computation time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make `allDocs` indexed by id, so that you don't need to `findIndex` every time. And avoid doing many small `splice`s on big arrays, rather mark them for deletion and then remove them all in one pass.

Comment: (Also: use a database for such large data :-)

Comment: Instead of doing operations like `x._id.toString()` 46K * 345K * (dupecount + 1) times, iterate the allDocs array once creating a new property which is this `x._id.toString()` (345K operations only).  Is x._id the entire object?  or some numeric/string ID?

Comment: Would it be possible to simply `resElem.dups = [resElem.dups[0]];` instead of the `resElem.dups.forEach` iteration? You want to end up with a new array that only contains the first entry in the old array, right? Seems simple enough

Comment: @Bergi I liked the idea about doing splice in one row. thanks. But i am still confuse how does indexing by id in an array work?

Comment: @James x._id is not the the entire object. it is just id like ObjectId("5b3b25b4e54029249c453d95") and therefore i have to convert it toString to get this 5b3b25b4e54029249c453d95 only

Comment: Your aggregation data structure example is wrong/misleading.  It looks like the _id property is the entire inner object.  Is this node.js, and are you using mongodb (the first search result for "javascript ObjectID")?  Might want to add those tags to your question if so.  I would imagine there is a much more efficient way to do this using your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the ideas from Bergi, we index the documents by id to avoid having to find the indexes which is expensive:

```
var allDocs =[345,000 objects]
var aggregationRes =[46,000 objects]
var allDocsIndexed = {};

allDocs.forEach(function(doc){
    allDocsIndexed[doc._id.toString()] = doc;
});

aggregationRes.forEach(function (resElem, counter) {
    allDocsIndexed[resElem.dups[0]].properties = resElem.dupsProp;
    for (var i = 1; i < resElem.dupsProp.length; i++) {
        delete allDocsIndexed[resElem.dupsProp[i]];
    }
});

var allUndeletedDocs = allDocs.filter(doc => allDocsIndexed.hasOwnProperty(doc_id.toString()));
```

Note that for javascript, this is an efficient solution but with more details provided, a better one might exist using mongodb features.

Comment: Hey... your solution was perfect. unbelievable. wooooooow, I can not believe that . it was supppppppppper fast. just in less than a minute, it did the whole calculation which i used to do it in 3 to 4 hours.  I did not know what people usually says about indexing an array but Now with your example I understood it very well. thanks a lot. Just a quick question: I did not used the last line (filtering) because i already have all the result. why do you actually filtered them ?

Comment: @MaryamKoulaei we only deleted the keys from allDocsIndexed, we never deleted anything from allDocs. So instead of deleting, I just filter to get the ones that were not deleted